Selenium can't find element on server, but can on local device
I'm trying to write a python script that will go to a website I host, wait for the external JavaScript file to load, and then retrieve some elements that it creates. And it works great on my machine, but when I run it on pythonanywhere, it gives me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/SmallCoder14/orthodox_saints_of_the_day/get_quotes.py", line 14, in <module>
    quote = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5f8f634cbe89 <unknown>


My code is:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://SmallCoder14.pythonanywhere.com/quote-of-the-day")

quote = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/p[1]"))
)

driver.quit()


I tried using implicitly_wait for 10 seconds instead of WebDriverWait for 10 seconds, but that yielded the same error. I also tried adding the --disable-dev-shm-usage argument, but that also yielded the same error

Could we please get a [mcve]?

@Robert sorry, forgot

Have you tried to run the selenium without headless to see if the quote is loaded? The error indicates 10 seconds may not be enough. The responding time on the remote server might be significantly slower than your local machine.

@RibomBalt if I remove --headless, it gives me this error:
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
    Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
      (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
      (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer 
    running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)


@user24067968 OK, even in headless mode you can still checks the result HTML with something like html = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'body').get_attribute('innerHTML'). For testing purpose you can try time.sleep for 10 seconds, run the above line to get the current HTML, and check if the target element exists.

@RibomBalt I waited for 60 seconds, and it still only finds the script. I printed the HTML from your code, and it only prints the script tag
